# Validating initials with regex in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, regex, validation

I want to validate my initials with regex in JavaScript, the rule should match any letter combination and should not be case sensitive.

Example (Liza Suki):

```
var a = "ls"; // valid
var b = "sl"; // valid
var c = "Ls"; // valid
var d = "LS"; // valid
var e = "lS"; // valid
var f = "Sl"; // valid
var g = "SL"; // valid
var h = "sL"; // valid
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: did you want to match `lsl`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Anchors must be a needed one.

```
/^[ls]{2}$/i
```

Try this if you don't want to match `ll` or `ss`

```
/^(?!(?:ss|ll)$)[ls]{2}$/i
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/wO6pK6/1)

Answer (score 4):

Try this one (the 'i' flag means, that regex is case-insensitive):

```
/(ls)|(sl)/i
```

https://regex101.com/r/mT8jW3/2

Comment: This will match 'LL' and 'SS' as well

Comment: That's true. I've fixed that.

Answer (score 2):

`i` is case insensitive, `g` is global:

```
/(ls)|(sl)/ig
```

Comment: You might want to anchor it: `/^(sl|ls)$/i`.

Answer (score 1):

```
var regex = /(ls)|(sl)/i;
console.log(regex.test('LS'));
console.log(regex.test('lS'));
console.log(regex.test('Ls'));
console.log(regex.test('sL'));
console.log(regex.test('ll'));
console.log(regex.test('SS'));
```

**Output**

```
true
true
true
true
false
false
```

Comment: this won't match `sl`

Comment: Ok...I though his initials was LS, not SL

Comment: Fixed it...by now, everyone else have also fixed it

Answer (score 1):

Here is a generic function that takes a name and input initials value and it validates whether name has same initials or not.

```
function isValid(name, ils) {
    var m = name.match(/\b[A-Z]/g);
    var re = new RegExp('^' + m.map(function(e){return '(?=.*?' + e + ')';}).join('') +
              '[' + m.join('') + ']{' + m.length + '}$', 'i');

    // Example: re = /^(?=.*?s)(?=.*?l)[sl]{2}$/i
    return re.test(ils);
}
```

**Testing:**

```
isValid('Liza Suki', 'sl')
true
isValid('Liza Suki', 'ss')
false
isValid('Liza Suki', 'ls')
true
isValid('Liza Suki', 'LS')
true
isValid('Liza Suki', 'LL')
false
isValid('Liza Suki', 'lsl')
false
```